# Spring profile on class and method level

Tags: spring, spring-profiles

Given the example below:

```
@Profile("testing")
@Configuration
public class SpringProfiles {

    @Bean
    @Profile("developement")
    public Profession profession1(){
        return Profession.builder()
                .name("professor")
                .description("professor in the university")
                .build();
    }

}
```

will the bean `profession1` be created when the two profiles("testing" and "developement") are activated?

Or the condition is only the developement profile should be active.

Comment: Have you tried to create one demo app to try this?Seems like very easy job.